# Define a protocol that mimics QFileSystemModel.index() and its overloads

Tags: python, mypy, pyqt6

I'm trying to implement a protocol that mimics QFileSystemModel so that I can use that protocol to define a new custom class. The protocol definition is generating a mypy error when trying to make sure that protocol is satisfied by current QFileSystemModel derived class.  Here is what I've tried...

```
import typing
from PyQt6 import QtCore, QtGui


class FileSystemModelProtocol(typing.Protocol):
    """Define the subset of QFileSystemModel methods used...for defining a class with the same behavior"""
    @typing.overload
    def index(self, row: int, column: int, parent: QtCore.QModelIndex = ...) -> QtCore.QModelIndex: ...
    @typing.overload
    # def index(self, path: typing.Optional[str], column: int = ...) -> QtCore.QModelIndex: ... path vs row causes an error
    def index(self, row: typing.Optional[str], column: int = ...) -> QtCore.QModelIndex: ...
    def index(self, row: typing.Optional[int | str] = ..., column: int = ..., parent: QtCore.QModelIndex = ...) -> QtCore.QModelIndex: ...


class CustomFileSystemModel(QtGui.QFileSystemModel, FileSystemModelProtocol):  # error: Definition of "index" in base class "QAbstractItemModel" is incompatible with definition in base class "FileSystemModelProtocol"
    pass


class TableModel(QtCore.QAbstractTableModel, FileSystemModelProtocol):
    def index_from_str(self, path: str) -> QtCore.QModelIndex:
        return QtCore.QModelIndex()  # TODO: lookup with path

    def index(self, row_path: typing.Optional[int | str] = None, column: int = 0, parent: QtCore.QModelIndex = QtCore.QModelIndex()) -> QtCore.QModelIndex:
        if isinstance(row_path, str):
            return self.index_from_str(row_path)
        if isinstance(row_path, int):
            return super().index(row_path, column, parent)
        return QtCore.QModelIndex()


c = CustomFileSystemModel()
t = TableModel()
```

*** Edited down to a more minimal example.  The previous edit showed some previous attempts as well as the relevant prototypes from the qt sources.  This should be just the relevant code. Mypy execution and results follow

*** Edit 2
Renaming path in the second overload to row made this error go away ...# error: Overloaded function implementation does not accept all possible arguments of signature 2

```
mypy file_system_protocol_test_so1.py 
file_system_protocol_test_so1.py:26: error: Definition of "index" in base class "QAbstractItemModel" is incompatible with definition in base class "FileSystemModelProtocol"  [misc]
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

Comment: Please identify the errors you are getting.

Comment: @itprorh66 There are 2 comments in the post showing the errors that occour.  ```# error: Overloaded function implementation does not accept all possible arguments of signature 2``` and ```# error: Definition of "index" in base class "QAbstractItemModel" is incompatible with definition in base class "FileSystemModelProtocol"```

Comment: @shao.lo There are also *a lot* of comments in your code, making it difficult to distinguish between what is irrelevant code, a proper comment, and the actual errors. Please review your question by providing only the code that matters, comments necessary for context that the code alone doesn't make clear, and *separately* show the errors you get. We shouldn't have to go through **all** the code (and its comments) first just to begin to understand what problems you get: that should normally be the last resource at most.

Comment: @musicamante updated to a more minimal example as requested.

Comment: @shao.lo I've never played around too much with type hinting: I understand its needs, but I've also seen too many people pointlessly banging their heads on it and for no *actual* valid reason, while forgetting the importance of what their code actually should do (focusing too much on typing, while their implementation was pure garbage in the meantime). That said, as opposed to C++, Python doesn't natively provide real overloads, which is what QFileSystemModel does for `index()`: `QAbstractItemModel.index()` and `QFileSystemModel.index()` have different and incompatible signatures. As far as »

Comment: @shao.lo » I can understand, the protocol definitions you're trying are not sufficient, probably due to the way PyQt internally creates its classes. Remember that PyQt is a binding, and it has to do some "magic" under the hood (including when creating subclasses and instances of them) in order to make things work as expected in the general behavior, which may be incompatible for such "low level" expectations that type hinting may require. As said, I've never really used type hinting, but AFAIK you can create "exceptions" to avoid issues like these. I'd suggest you to look into them.

Comment: @musicamante I tried pyright and pytype.  Neither of them report errors on this code, so I'm thinking it might be a mypy bug.